# How can I have single worksheet in .CSV converted from multiple worksheets of .xlsx file

Tags: excel, csv, xlsx

How can I convert a multiple worksheet .xlsx file into a single worksheet(containing all 3 worksheets info > means merged) .CSV file.

I can just do the save into other format in microsoft excel, it doesnt merge all the sheets.

How can I have a single sheet containing all the info in .csv format.

Here is the Ex file: [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54s5NXDypdMaVF5QjVxeG4wUDA/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isn't automatically supported simply because it's not always clear how this should be done. Also, it involves loss of information - having merged all the sheets, how would you un-merge them later if you re-opened the file. What if it was important to the meaning of the date which sheet it was in?

I'd simply suggest using Excel to copy the data from each sheet into a new sheet containing all the data merged exactly as you would like, then save that sheet as csv.

Comment: I can do that manually, but the files are huge and as you can see from the file i have attached (its an Example file), I have three experiments data that I want to merge into one, no date information. So I think there wont be any loss of information. And also I can remove the 2nd header line , and all the column names will remain same throughout.